# Expected value given probability density function

Tags: probability, functions, conditional-expectation, variance

I am struggling to see the relationship between the left and right side of the equation [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Zrm.png):

$$\mathbb E\left[\left( e^K \right)^2\right]=\large{e^{2\sigma^2_K}}$$

with $K\sim \mathcal N\left(0,\sigma_K^2\right)$

I know that you are supposed to show the relationship by the probability density function given a mean and variance, but I do not know how to proceed. Could anyone help me?

Comment: How is $X$ distributed ? And have you omitted further information ?

Comment: Forget about the conditional expression. I updated the expression in the post. K is normally distributed with a mean of zero.

Comment: Is it X that you said to be normally distributed?

Comment: X is no longer part of the expression(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected value of $(e^K)^2=e^{2K}$ is

$$\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{2k}\cdot e^{-k^2/(2\sigma^2)}} \,dk$$

$$\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{4k\sigma^2/(2\sigma^2)}\cdot e^{-k^2/(2\sigma^2)}} \,dk$$

We can put together the exponents in a quadratic expression by completing the squares.

$-(k^2-4k\sigma^2+4\sigma^4)+4\sigma^4=-(k-2\sigma^2)^2+4\sigma^4$

$$\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{4\sigma^4/(2\sigma^2)}\cdot e^{-(k-2\sigma^2)^2/(2\sigma^2)}} \,dk$$

$$\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{2\sigma^2}\cdot e^{-(k-2\sigma^2)^2/(2\sigma^2)}} \,dk$$

$$e^{2\sigma^2}\cdot \underbrace{\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}  e^{-(k-2\sigma^2)^2/(2\sigma^2)}} \,dk}_{=1}$$

The expression behind $e^{2\sigma^2}$ is the integral of the pdf of a normal distributed variable. The value is is well known.

Comment: The kind of operations you did by adding and substracting the same term in the exponent and moving a part of it out of the integral. Can you do that with any values, and still make the integral add up to 1? Won't the term you moved out of the integral make the integral add up to something different than 1?

Comment: @okkitru The integral (including the leading factor) is the integral you know from the normal distribution with the expected value of $2\sigma^2$ (constant) and the variance $\sigma^2$. This integral is equal to 1. That was the purpose of the whole transformations, especially  completing the squares. And the additional factor $e^{2\sigma^2}$ has been factored out. It is not needed for the integral being equal to 1. I have made an small edit to show which expression is equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried you method on an extention of the expression above, but I cannot seem to see the relations in this one. I created a new question because the two expressions are kind of different. It is found here: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032086/expected-value-of-exponential-function-given-density-function)