# Expected value of exponential function given density function

Tags: probability-distributions, standard-deviation, density-function

I am struggling to see the relationship between the left and right side of the equation below:

[image]

$$E(e^{p+q})=e^{(\sigma^2_p/2)+(\sigma^2_q/2)+r}$$

Both "p" and "q" are normally distributed with a mean of zero. I know that you are supposed to show the relationship by the probability density function given a mean and variance, but I do not know how to proceed. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What is $r$ in the question?

Comment: Hint: Compute the variance of $p+q$ in terms of $(\sigma_p^2,\sigma_q^2,r)$.

Comment: @Did I know that the var(p+q)=Var(p)+Var(q)+2cov(p+q). However, I do not understand how I can proceed with this result to get to the right side of the expression. Btw, this is an extention to another expression: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031520/expected-value-given-probability-density-function). However, I do not see the clear connection when using the probability density distribution and function.

Comment: *Even before asking this*, you should be aware of the value of $E(e^x)$ where $x$ is centered normal with variance $s$... If you were, you would very much "understand how (one) can proceed with this result to get to the right side of the expression".

Comment: Is $r$ somehow specified ?

Comment: @callculus I am actually not sure. That is also something that confuses me.

Comment: @Did This field is new to me, so I am trying to learn. I have tried to start of with some calculations. Could you see if I am at least on the right direction? See here: [link](https://s16.postimg.org/fstvqj651/Equation.png)

Comment: @Did I know that E(exp(x))=exp(var(x)/2). Hence, I would assume that E(exp(p+q)) = exp((var(p)/2)+(var(q)/2)). However, the term r confuses me.

Comment: you might be missing one crucial piece of information here: what is the **joint** distribution of $p$ and $q$? I'm (strongly) guessing that they are jointly normal with some correlation coefficient $\rho$. Then the sum $p+q$ follows again a normal distribution. You can compute the mean and variance of $p+q$ and apply your formulas to get the right hand side. Then you can identify the term $r$ that is confusing you.

Comment: "Hence, I would assume that E(exp(p+q)) = exp((var(p)/2)+(var(q)/2))" Sorry but you said yourself that var(p+q) is var(p)+var(q)+2cov(p,q), hence E(exp(p+q)) is not exp((var(p)/2)+(var(q)/2)) but rather...

Comment: @Did exp((var(p)/2)+(var(q)/2)+cov(p,q)). But why should one consern about the variance? My guess would be to split the expectation so that we get E[exp(p)]*E[exp(q)] and get my first result. Obviously, that is incorrect. However, I don't see how the variance gets involved.

Comment: Quote: "I know that E(exp(x))=exp(var(x)/2)" Thus, to compute E(exp(p+q)), you need var(p+q), right?

Comment: @Did So it is simply enough to state that given E(exp(x))=exp(var(x)/2), we also have E(exp(p+q))=exp(var(p+q)/2), which then gives us E(exp(p+q))=exp(var(p)/2+var(q)/2+cov(p,q))?

Comment: Yes. With cov(p,q)=r.